# How to write a loop which checks all special values and put the number of this values to every gene_id

Tags: r

There are two dataframes: introns and gene_count. There is column in Introns - V3 - it shows the type of RNA sample (exon, intron and etc). There is column V9, it has information what gene possesses this RNA sample. There is an empty column ExonN in gene_count which needed to be fulled by the numbers of exons of each gene. gene_count has the column gene_id, which is the same as V9, but it exists only once in this sheet. So i tried this:

for (i in introns$V3) {
if (i == 'exon') {
gene_count_pv$ExonN
}
}

But this is, of course, stupid and naive

Comment: please share a few (sample) rows of both datasets and also your expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to populate the column "ExonN" in the dataframe `gene_count` (`gene_count$ExonN`) with the number of exons contained in the corresponding gene. Where genes are uniquely identified in both `introns` and `gene_count` by a gene ID, which is the column `V9` in `introns` and the column `gene_id` in `gene_count`.

This can be done fairly simply with the package `dplyr`.

First you'll want to tabulate the number of exons for each gene.

```
library(dplyr)

exon_count <- group_by(introns, gene_id = V9) %>% # Group the dataframe by each gene ID
   summarise(num_exons = sum(V3 == "exon")) # For each gene ID, count the number of rows where the sample type is "exon"
```

Finally, you'll want to join the information about exon_counts to the `gene_count`  dataframe.

```
left_join(gene_count, exon_count, by = c("gene_id"))
```